# Assign value to Column in an SQL Alchemy upon its save/creation

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a class `user` in my database and I want to assign `avatar_file_name` a random value every-time a new user is created essentially "on save". How can I accomplish this?

Array of Data that will randomly be chosen from

```
avatarImages = [
    "blue-dino_128.png",
    "brown-dino_128.png",
    "green-dino_128.png",
    "orange-dino_128.png",
    "pink-dino_128.png",
    "purple-dino_128.png",
  ]
```

This is the class and be default it selects a random string name from the array but I think there is a better way to accomplish this.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String(50), nullable=True)
    avatar_file_name = Column(String(100), nullable=True, default=random.choice(avatarImages)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default=random.choice(avatarImages)` is executed only once, so the same value will be selected for every user.  To get a random selection for each user, make the call to `random.choice` in a `lambda`:

```py
default=lambda: random.choice(avatarImages)
```